# Minimum value of $a^2 + b^2$ so that the quadratic $x^2 + ax + (b+2) = 0$ has real roots

Tags: functions, quadratics, discriminant

> The equation $ x^2 + ax + (b+2) = 0 $ has real roots, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.
>
> How would I find the minimum value of $a^2 + b^2$ ?

Comment: You get a "closE" for effort?

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I was meant to put my progress in the question. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 4):

Using what you already did ( the discriminant is no-negative and thus $\;a^2-4b\ge8\;$) then

$$a^2+b^2\ge8+4b+b^2=(b+2)^2+4$$

So the above rightmost expression is at least...

Comment: Sorry if this may sound stupid, but what happens to the a?

Comment: For $\;a\;$ you get $\;a^2>4b+8\;$ so you just substitute at the center expression, and $\;b^2\;$ stays.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your solution is the most clear.

Comment: Just quickly wondering, isn't a^2 GREATER than 8+4b but not equal to it? So can you just substitute it in like that?

Comment: I think it should be $\;a^2-4b \geq 8\;$ since the discriminant can be zero.

Comment: @Sawarnik Indeed, thank you. I thought it said tow different roots but it actually doesn't, so the discriminant can vanish.

Comment: How would you explain your reasoning for subbing in the equality in stead of the inequality?

Comment: I sort of have a clue but I don't know how to put it into words.

Comment: @differentialequation If $\;b=-2\;$ then it must be $\;a^4\ge16\;$ , and the minimum possible is $\;4\;$ .

Comment: Correction to the above:  $\;a^2\ge 16\;$

Comment: In submitting a formal solution, I mean, how could I explain substituting in a^2 = 4b+8 as a^2 can also be > 4b+8.

Comment: @differentialequation Of course you can...and you should. The $\;<,\,>,\,\le,\,\ge\;$ relations are *transitive*.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does 'transistive' mean? I looked it up but I'm not clear about how that applies to the inequality. @DonAntonio

Comment: @differentialequation It means that from $\;a\ge b\;$ an $\;b\ge c\;$ it follows that $\;a\ge c\;$ . In our case, we have $\;b^2+a^2\ge 0\;$ and $\;a^2\ge 4b+8\;$ so that $\;b^2+a^2\ge b^2+2b+8\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the $(a,b)$ plane, the point $(a,b)$ has to be *under* the parabola $a^2-4b =8$. The point of this domain closest to origin  is the vertex of the parabola, $(0,-2)$. Hence the minimum of $a^2+b^2$ is $4$.

Comment: How do I know that it is an (a,b) plane rather than a (b,a) plane?

Comment: That's your choice. If you decide for the $(b,a)$, the phrasing would be: ‘the domain is the set of points $(b,a)$ *outside*  of the parabola’ (which would have a  horizontal axis).

Answer (score 1):

We get the solutions
$$
0 = x^2 + a x + b + 2 = (x + a/2)^2 - a^2/4 + b + 2 \iff \\
x = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4b - 8}}{2}
$$
which are real for
$$
a^2 - 4b - 8 \ge 0
$$
We now want to solve the optimization problem
\begin{matrix}
\min & a^2 + b^2 \\
\text{w.r.t} & a^2 - 4b - 8 \ge 0
\end{matrix}
[image]

The above image shows the function
$$
z = f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2
$$
(red surface). It is rotational symmetric around the $z$-axis and has circles in the $x$-$y$-plane with center $(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt{c}$ as isolines $f(x,y) = c$ (yellow). 
The curve 
$$
x^2 - 4y - 8 = 0 \iff \\
y = (1/4) x^2 - 2 
$$
(green) is the border of the feasible area $x^2 - 4y -8 \ge 0$, shown in light blue. Point $A=(2,0)$ (pink) is not feasible with the condition, $B=(2,-2)$ (blue) is a feasible point.

Going from inner to outer isolines, we see that the isoline with radius $r=2$, thus $x^2 + y^2 = 2^2 = 4 = c$ is the first one to be part of the feasible area. Thus the minimum is $4$.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put into this solution, especially the graphical representation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you put b= -2 then then equation becomes an equation with x value as zero which is real..

So minimum value of expression will be four if we put a equals zero..